# Appcelerator Titanium Mobile: app.js not found

Tags: iphone, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I created an app with Appcelerator's Titanium Mobile on my home machine.  The path was /Users/[myusername]/Projects/ProjectName.

I checked my code into Mercurial.

The next day, at my office computer, I cloned the Mercurial repo, and then added the existing app.  I tried to run it in the simulator and received the error:

`could not find the file app.js`.

I looked at the log and noticed that the path it was looking for was the path on my home computer, not the path on my office computer.

What can I do to make my app run on two different computers?  I imagine that if I created a new app and then copied my code into it, it would probably work on the office machine.  But if I checked my code in, and got latest at home it would probably be broken there.

Comment: There seems to be a line in the main.m file that sets the constant TI_APPLICATION_RESOURCE_DIR.  Apparently this doesn't get regenerated when I re-launch the simulator.  Is there a way to force a complete rebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open tiapp.xml
2. Remove the line. f01a795a-46e7-4627-8558-465e5998c99d
3. Do a full rebuild
4. Bring guid tag back (just to make sure you still have it on tiapp.xml)
5. Do a full rebuild again.

Here's the source:

http://www.limechalk.com/blog/fix-runtime-error-when-running-appcelerator-app-on-android-emulator/

Comment: That line not exist in my tiapp.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Can you re-create a new project? copy your files tiapp.xml as well as folder Resources to your new project and build again.

Answer (score 0):

This issue mainly caused by JavaScript minification,either you have syntax error in one or more js files or which is hard to predict may you have some other files in you project that are not js files and cause this failure to build and then this common error . 
my two cents open up you project files and look carefully for any file or files that are not supposed to be in it.